# angular 8, How to store static HTML file inside custom packge?

Tags: angular, redirect, package, static-files

I have an angular custom  package that i made and i have multiple applications that consume that package.
I want to store a static HTML file inside my packge so that all the apps can access that file.

** The applications need to redirect to that HTML file on new tab in the explorer

how do i manage to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: As I understood, you want to reuse an angular html template which is in your angular package? If so, is it for reusing it as template of other components?

Comment: yes, it is a hard coded template and i want to navigate to this html file from other angular applications that consume this package.

Comment: did my answer provide the solution you wanted?

Comment: It was a good option but i decided to exclude the template from the package. for other reasons. thank you !!!

Comment: Your welcome! If my answer was correct for your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define a global constant that has inline template like below in any ts file of your package.

```
export const myTemplate =`html content`;
```

In order to use this constant template from consumer packages import it and define it like below.

```
import { myTemplate } “your-package/your-file”;

@Component({
  selector: “my-app”
  template:  myTemplate
})
export class MyAppComponent {}
```